# Newest tracks don't come up on top in embedded Spotify playlist?

Tags: spotify, playlist

When I embed a Spotify playlist, the oldest tracks come up on top. Is there any way to to make the newest tracks come up on top instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the Play button (I assume that's what you're using) displays the playlist in the playlist's order - if the user manually drags tracks to the top, they'll be at the top.

The problem here is that by default, the Spotify clients add new tracks to the end of the playlist. Changing that would need a change in the Spotify clients, which obviously is beyond the scope of this problem.